# How do I enable or disable a column of textboxes?

Tags: c#

Now I want to enable or disable that column of textboxes in the best possible way, perhaps not using array or loops. How do I do it?

```
// create a column of textboxes dynamically
   private void CreateControl(int ControlId)
{

            CheckBox control1 = new CheckBox();

            control1.Click += new EventHandler(chk_CheckedChanged);

            Point point = GetPoint(ControlId);
        control1.Location = point;
        this.Controls.Add(control1);


}

// a check box to enable or disable that column of textboxes
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Column column = new Column();
  CheckBox  chk = (CheckBox) sender;
  if (chk.Checked)
  {


      column.EnterName.Enabled = true;
// I want to enable or disable the entire column of textboxes

  }
}


Public Class Column 
{
  public TextBox EnterName {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: y dont you want to use arrays or loops?

Answer (score 1):

- Add a GroupBox or a Panel (if you dont create the illusion of there's nothing there.. no border) to house the column of textboxes
- Toggle the Enabled property of the Groupbox as required.

I think that'd work.